# What is the correct way to include a user defined function inside a FormFunction wrapper?

Tags: function-construction, cloud-deploy, form-building

I'm planning to wrap my `FormFunction` expression in `Cloulddeploy` but am having trouble giving input to the required data to `Encde`, the function I want to run inside `FormFunction`. `Encde` runs fine in a notebook on its own, but not inside `FormFunction`. The websites I've looked at for help (with my untrained eye, including Mathematic.SE) seem to offer contradictory examples of how the function is suppose to be formatted inside `FormFunction`.

What is the correct way to include a user defined function inside a `FormFunction` expression?

```
Encde[v1_, p1_] := 
 TableForm[
  Flatten[
   ToUpperCase[
    IntegerString[
     {Times[ToExpression[ToCharacterCode[v1]], p1]}, 16]] 
    ], TableDirections ->Row
   ]

FormFunction[{"v1"->"String", "p1"->"Integer"}, Encde]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form functions get an association from the input dialog, so try

```
Encde[input_] := 
  TableForm[
    Flatten[ToUpperCase[
      IntegerString[{Times[ToExpression[ToCharacterCode[input["v1"]]], input["p1"]]}, 16]]], 
    TableDirections -> Row]

FormFunction[{"v1" -> "String", "p1" -> "Integer"}, Encde]
```

[image: ff1]

[image: ff2]

Comment: Thanks. Small improvement running in this code this morning. Unforuately, even with copy and pasting directly, my code is still not initiating the wrapped function in a notebook. It is triggering when deployed however but then not displaying in 'tableform'. I will have to investigate more later today.

Comment: Would there be a reason when I copy your example and execute it, it wouldn't generate the submit button in the notebook?

Comment: @BBirdsell. Really? As you can see from my post, on my system, the Submit appears. I don't what to say without seeing your notebook. Can only suggest trying my code all by itself in a fresh notebook in a fresh Mathematica session.

Comment: Actually I should try that but am beginning to suspect (FYI) it's a quirk of MMA Online after investigating the error message further. I really love MMA Online but wasn't expecting problems with common functions like `FormFunction`. In any case, I did learn something your answer and I'm not the sort of person to get worked up about bugs in the online platform because I bet it's pretty complicated to get something like MMA working perfectly smoothly in the cloud and WF seems pretty determined to keep refining their could products.